# How to make an animation go back to origin point using Expression Blend

Tags: wpf, animation, expression-blend

I'm trying to make a simple animation using `Expression Blend` in which I have a `Line` that acts as the `MotionPath` of a circle.

I made the animation start at one point of the line and end in the finishing point of the line path.

[image]

The ball starts at point `1`. The line path ends at point `2`. That's working fine. I need the ball to go back to point `1` and then repeat the behaviour forever (I know how to get this repeat behaviour part).

How can I make the ball go back to point `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xaml for your Animation just add the below property

```
 RepeatBehavior="Forever"
```

This should repeat the animation continuously.

Comment: That makes it repeat go from left to right forever, but I also want the shape to go back to the left point and then repeat forever.

Comment: Add AutoReverse="True" property then. That should go back to the start point.

Comment: It is on the storyboard. If you are using blend, then select the storyboard in Objects and Timeline panel then you can change the property in the PropertyGrid. Or in xaml just that property to your storyboard